# Applying after UK visa refusal

Tags: uk-visa, refusal, overstay

I was refused a UK visitor visa due to an overstay on my Tier 4 visa. I was in the UK on the Tier 4 visa from February 2012 to March 2014, at which time I applied for an extension and stayed in the country.

I was notified in September 2014 that my case had been assigned to an officer. In January, when I had heard nothing further, I asked to withdraw my application and was first told that my documents would be returned to me. Shortly after that, I was told by email that my documents had been lost in the mail.

In April 2015, I received another email saying that UKBA was holding my documents. Again, I asked for them to be returned to me so that I could leave the country. I returned to India on 17th May 2015.

Now they have refused my visit visa, asking what I was doing in the UK between  September 2014 to May 2015, after my sponsor's license had been revoked. I left the UK voluntarily and bought my own ticket.

Should apply again for the visit visa, and also attach all the emails I received from UKBA between September 2014 and May 2015?

Comment: When you were told the documents were lost, why didn't you apply for a new passport and leave the country?

Comment: My passport was with voluntary departure team but my documents as in my marksheets and degrees and all other documents were with ukba.i could leave the country without them as it is very difficult to get them back

Comment: I still don't understand why you didn't leave in January or February? If the supporting documents were lost,  and you'd asked to withdraw your application,  why not leave? Did they tell you that they were trying to find the documents?

Comment: Yes they told me they give me a tracking no too and I followed up with Royal Mail but we couldn't find the docs. I told them that how could I leave the country without my docs and they agreed to it. So I left the country as soon as I got my docs

Comment: Till Feb I was waiting for my docs from ukba. But when I did not receive anything from them after a month of withdrawal of my application I got worried and then I was told that the docs are lost and that I need to wait for sometime I was fortunate enough that they found my docs in April otherwise how would hai survived as the documents are very necessary

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because visitor visa questions go on Travel